# C++ to vb.net TCHAR array use conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, tchar

I'm not a c++ programmer, I need to convert this c++ code to vb.net:

```
int iRC = 0;            
TCHAR ptcTemp[20];
_itot_s(iRC, ptcTemp, sizeof(ptcTemp), 10);
```

I don't really understand, all I know is that this is a conversion of an Int to a TCHAR array.

I was wondering if

```
Dim ptcTemp As String = iRC.ToString()
```

Would work or maybe I'll miss something?

Any help is apreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: ToString() is fine.  Life is easy with a garbage collector and a standard string type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_itot_s = integer to t with security

- i integer
- to
- t, type t, this is because C++ can have ASCII or UNICODE, this source code can be compiled as either.
- s security/safe version, the function has 2 parameters for the buffer, the buffer and its length, so the function can prevent a buffer overload.

The 10 is so the string is a decimal, other popular options are 2 binary, 8 octal, 16 hex.

What you are doing will work OK.